# Transferring files in pc to Android

Tags: android, file, sockets, transfer

Well, I want to start a new project, but I have a question at the begin.

What technology do I have to use to transfer a file from a pc to a android phone? I already did a project where I transfered a file prom pc to pc using socket and server socket, but now I don't know if it is the better way.

What do you think I should use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DownloadManager maybe?

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#DownloadManager.Request%28android.net.Uri%29

Too tired to write an example, going to sleep, but checkout for example:

http://www.vogella.com/blog/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/